# Is there any DAX query for calculate the ratio of distinct value

Tags: sqlite, powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-cleaning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ0j3.png)I have calculated ratio of distinct values from same col in power bi by using new measure, after calculating it I have put that result in card it is not showing result correctly

I have calculated the ratio of distinct values from same column by using some formulae

```
// 1
DistinctValuesCount = COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('YourTableName'[DistinctValues]))) 

// 2
TotalDistinctValuesCount = COUNTROWS('YourTableName')

// 3
DistinctValuesRatio = DIVIDE([DistinctValuesCount], [TotalDistinctValuesCount])
```

and at the end of calculation, after I put that result in card, its not giving me any count its giving me the 2.54E-5
what does it mean
as image is showing the result of calculated ratio, so where am going wrong ?

Comment: `2.54E-5` = `0.0000254`. `E` in numbers is shorthand for `10^`. With knowing that - is there any further help you need?

Comment: @SamNseir I guess I am not able to put forward what exact the issue is,                                               can I share the screenshot maybe from that you will get the idea of it ?

Comment: What are you wanting to know? How many values  are duplicated? If you provide an example then we can help.

Comment: Sir, am working on a pbi dashboard where I want to calculate the ratio of disctinct blood groups, and I want those values to put in card visual

Comment: Define "ratio of distinct blood groups". For example, There is a table with 10 rows, in one column there are 3 As and  3 Bs and 4 Cs - what does distinct ratio mean ? Update your question with an example [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) with a few rows, and explain what the desired result should be.

Comment: Yes you can share a screen shot, edit your question above and paste the image in.

Comment: as image is showing the result of calculated ratio, so where am going wrong ?

Comment: Explain what it is you want to see in the bottom card. Right now it is showing `11 / 433,000`.

Comment: I want ratio of each blood group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the percentage of a Blood group.
Create a new measure with:

```
Overall % =
  DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS('YourTableName'),
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('YourTableName'), ALL('YourTableName') )
  )
```

Then under `Measure tools` tab in the ribbon, click on the `%` and choose how many decimal places you want.

Now use this in your card. It should show 100% since no Blood Group has been selected. Now click on a row in your Matrix, and the card should update with the % of that Blood Group.

Comment: yes, I want to show the percentage of each blood group, I used the below formula it's giving me the same percentage in matrix table i.e 9.09%

Comment: if distinct count is different for each blood grp then why it's giving me the same % value ?

Comment: Update my answer to look at your data table, not the blood group table. Which table has all the row data?

Comment: sorry 
am not getting you
can you please share your mail id

Comment: I got your point, Thank you for help.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.

Comment: Have accepted the answer, thank you once again.